# Clarification of REST concepts (with PHP)

Tags: php, rest, curl

I'm a bit confused with a few concepts of REST and I'd appreciate some clarification. I'm following this tutorial, so any code I use is from it.  http://phpmaster.com/rest-can-you-do-more-than-spell-it-3/

**1). Anytime I want to post data, do I have to go through this whole procedure of a curl transaction?**

```
<?php
// set up the URI value involved in a variable
$uri = "http://www.funland.com/summerschedule";

// set up the data that is going to be passed
$events = array(
array("event" => "20120601-0001",
      "name"  => "AC/DC Drink Till U Drop Concert",
      "date"  => "20120601",
      "time"  => "22000030"),
array("event" => "20120602-0001",
      "name"  => "Enya – Can You Feel the Peace",
      "date"  => "20120602",  
      "time"  => "19300045"),
array("event" => "20120603-0002",
      "name"  => "Nicki Menaj – The Midnight Girls Concerrtt",
      "date"  => "20120603",  
      "time"  => "21300039"));
$jsonData = json_encode($events) 

// perform the curl transaction
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);

$response = curl_exec($ch); 
$decode = json_decode($response);
print_r($resonse);
```

**2. Whenever I'm creating a link, is there something special I have to do as far as the URI goes, or would I just format it according to how it would be accessed?**

To make a link to www.example.com/restaurant/42 would I make the following link, or is there something else I have to do?

```
//assuming $resource = restaurant in this example

<a href ="www.example.com/".$resource."/".$id">Item 42</a>
```

**3. For the code that parses the URL's path, do I have this in every single file, or would I create a file (such as api.php) and just include that in each file?**

```
<?php
// assume autoloader available and configured
$path = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
$path = trim($path, "/");
@list($resource, $params) = explode("/", $path, 2);

$resource = ucfirst(strtolower($resource));
$method = strtolower($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]);
$params = !empty($params) ? explode("/", $params) : array();

if (class_exists($resource)) {
   try {
     $resource = new $resource($params);
     $resource->{$method}();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
}
}
else {
  header("HTTP/1.1 404 File Not Found");
}
```

**4. Where do I set the acceptable "verbs" for each function of a certain class?** The following code is from part 2 of the tutorial linked above. I see that there is a class constructor, but am I supposed to specify the accepted actions for each function there? Maybe I'm misunderstanding this code, but I don't see where it says that DELETE is not accepted for something like Restaurant/id

```
<?php
abstract class Resource
{
    protected static $httpMethods = array("GET", "POST", "HEAD",
    "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "TRACE", "CONNECT"); 

protected $params;

public function __construct(array $params) {
    $this->params = $params;
}

protected function allowedHttpMethods() {
    $myMethods = array();
    $r = new \ReflectionClass($this);
    foreach ($r->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC) as $rm) {
        $myMethods[] = strtoupper($rm->name);
    }
    return array_intersect(self::$httpMethods, $myMethods);

}

public function __call($method, $arguments) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed", true, 405);
    header("Allow: " . join($this->allowedHttpMethods(), ", "));
}
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow works best if you ask one specific question of the problem you are having.

Comment: So where should I post then? I'm asking specific questions about the concept.

Comment: Sounds to me like you understand the *concept* well enough, you just have several separate questions about how to structure your code for *implementing* the concept. Can you either boil it down to one common question or split it up into multiple questions?

Comment: @deceze I guess I'm most confused about question #4 above.

Comment: As with many things optimizing in multiple directions can lead to objective contradictions. What are you trying to achieve? A REST API in PHP that "performs best" / "is easy to use" / "is easy to extend" / "is very basic"

Comment: I'm just trying to get a hang of the basics, so that would probably fall under "is very basic/easy to use"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order:

1. You can write a function that encapsulates the whole cURL ditty.
2. Not sure what `$resource` and `$id` point to, but it seems to make sense that way; note that URL should start with `http://` or `https://`.
3. That code looks like a typical router and should get called at every request; make sure to set up your auto-loader before that code so that your classes get loaded automatically.
4. All your resource classes will extend from that base class; by creating `public function get() { }` in your class, the router will automatically call that method in case of a `GET` method; whatever you don't implement will cause `__call()` to run which will serve an error code to the REST client.

Comment: For #1, would I put that function in my api.php file? (which would then be included on each page). #3 Auto loader would just be a class constructor, right? Or is it a constructor for class constructors?

Comment: Yes, probably. For auto loader, check out `spl_autoload_register()`

Comment: @user1104854 np~ have fun with it :)

Comment: One more question - On #1 above, $uri is declared at the top, but when the curl transaction ocurrs, a variable called $url is used. Is this a mistake (remember, this code was copied from a tutorial) or am I not seeing something?

Comment: Seems like typo to me :)

Answer (score 0):

Responding to Q4 - my favourite approach would be to create an interface representing the HTTP process and check against that interface using `method_exists()` before executing the method on the called resource.

```
// declaring the methods
interface HTTP {
    public function get();
    public function post();
    public function put();
    ....
}

// checking if the attempted method is allowable
method_exists('HTTP', $method);
```

Comment: The flaw with this approach is that every resource in your applications won't support the same methods except in very basic, cookie-cutter implementations. Further, HTTP is extendable. i.e. custom methods like `ZANZIBAR` are possible. This is why we can have things like WEBDAV.

Comment: Why would the `Resource` class and its descendants not support the same methods? You can declare that `Resource` as implements `HTTP`. In the respect of flexibility indeed the static method approach is much more useful.

Comment: You can also create a basic interface (ex.`HTTP`) that implements the common methods and extend that interface with various other interfaces that are based upon the HTTP protocol. Indeed that would prompt the need to find out what interfaces each `Resource` implements and test it against that - which makes the process more complicated.

Comment: Simple example: My `/` resource supports `GET` only. It doesn't accept `POST` or `PUT` or `DELETE`. All it does is provide hypertext information informing the client of what resources are available from the service. Should I have an interface that only supports `GET` and then extend that to support `POST` for resources that support `GET` and `POST`? Using a single interface -- though it's what you'll usually see from framework "REST" implementations -- is only useful for cookie-cutter solutions.